# 2nd order differential equation which not in general form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a really hard time solving this problem.

$(1-x^2)y^{\prime \prime} - xy^{\prime} + y = 6x$

I basically tried the

**Power series**

method and

**Frobenius method**

to solve this. But in both cases the general equation doesn't include any constant like **$-6x$** in this case.. But I'm pretty sure there must be a tricky way for solving this. I'm running out of time and any kind of help will be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you find that the homogeneous DE $(1-x^2)y^{\prime \prime} - xy^{\prime} + y = 0$ has one solution $y=x$, can you then find a second linearly independent solution?  And then can you apply variation of parameters to get the solution to the original DE?

Comment: Let assume the solution of the above equation is y = a + ax1 + ax2 ... . Then how can I find a second linear independent solution. Please explain your method bit more...

Comment: The method should be in all DE textbooks.  If we know solution $y=x$ we try to find another solution of the form $xu$; substitute $y=xu$ in the homogeneous DE to get a first-order DE for $u'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as for a homogeneous differential equation take the ansatz 
$$y_p = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k.$$
Plug this into the inhomogeneous differential equation and collect terms in powers of $x$, $$\begin{equation*}
(a_0+2 a_2)
+\left(6 a_3-6\right) x
+\left(12 a_4-3 a_2\right) x^2
+\left(20 a_5-8 a_3\right) x^3
+\ldots = 0.\tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$
To find the particular solution we can set $a_0 = a_1 = 0$. 
This amounts to casting out linear combinations of the homogeneous solutions. 
Thus, 
$$y_p = x^3 + \frac{2}{5}x^5 + \ldots.$$
We can also read off the homogeneous solutions from (1), 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
y_1 &=& a_0\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{8} x^4 + \ldots\right) \\ 
y_2 &=& a_1 x. 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The solutions $y_1$, $y_2$, and $y_p$ can be found exactly following the steps laid out by @GEdgar in the comments.
I recommend finding them and verifying that their Taylor expansions yield the series solutions given above.